# Помочь с кодом на с++

Tags: c++

Программа написана верно, но она не работает. Не могу понять где ошибка. Вторая функция не выполняется.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
void getA(int q);
int main()
{
int q;
void getA(int q);
cout<<"Введите цифру, под которой назначена фигура"<<endl;
cout<<"\n 1.Параллелограм \n 2.Ромб \n 3.Трапеция \n 4.Четырёхугольник \n 5.Круг \n 6.Элипс\n";
cin>>q;
return 0;
}

void getA() {
int q;
cin>>q;
switch(q) {
case 1: cout<<"Параллелограмм","S = a · h\n S = a · b · sin α\nS= (d1 · d2 · sin y)/2\n"; break;
case 2: cout<<"Ромб","S = a · h\n S = a^2 · sin α'\n(d1 · d2)/2\n"; break;
case 3: cout<<"Трапеция","S= sqrt( p*(p-a) * (p-b) * (p-c) )\np=( a+b+c )/ 2\nS= ( h* ( a+b ) )/ 2"; break;
case 4: cout<<"Четырехугольник","S = √(p - a)(p - b)(p - c)(p - d) - abcd cos2θ\nS = p · r\nS= (d1 · d2 · sin y)/2"; break;
case 5: cout<<"Круг","S = π * r ^ 2\nS= (π * d ^ 2)/4"; break;
case 6: cout<<"Элипс","S = π · a · b"; break;
}
}
```

Comment: "*программа написана верно, но она не работает*" — как-то забавно звучит. Я готов вам помочь, и плевать, что после этого программа не заработает — помощь-то будет правильной, а это главное :) Ладно, вы просто ни разу, нигде **не вызываете** вторую функцию...

Comment: Как мне ее вызвать?

Comment: имя функции, открывающая скобка, аргументы через запятую, закрывающая скобка...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

qq, ты неправильно функцию вызвал, вместо void getA(int q) нужно getA(q),
тебе не нужно в функции объявлять q и просить пользователя дать значение q,
еще в main() ты сначала вызываешь getA(q) и только потом q присваивается значение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код следует вставлять текстом, а не скриншотом.